# MVC RedirectToAction calls Session_Start() in global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies, session-state

I am calling RedirectToAction method to call action method from another controller but it clears all session data
I debugged in global.asax and found out that when ever i call RedirectToAction it calls Session_Start() method.
I don't know how session start is called.
Here is my web config code for form and session tag

for session tag

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

and for form tag

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/ControllerName/ActionName" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

this "~/ControllerName/ActionName" is same method from wher i am calling "RedirecToAction"

just for info what i am trying is if i found cookies for user he will be redirected to home page from login page directly

both action methods are in different controller and in different Areas.
here is code which uses "RedirecToAction" method

```
public class LoginController : Controller{
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null && Request.Cookies["Password"] != null)
    {
        FillLoginSession();//Fills Session with user data ex. Session["User_Id"] = 1;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Home" });
    }
}}
```

and here is action method in another controller to which i am redirecting.

```
public class HomeController : Controller{
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got solution to this problem.
i was calling this

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
```

before initializing session from my method.
In my IIS this key "ASP.NET_SessionId" was used to store session in cookies.
as it was cleared it reinitialize everything when ever I redirect to new page.

Answer (score 0):

Forms Authentication and Session State are 2 different and unrelated things.

Although you haven't shown the method that calls `RedirectToAction`, I suspect that you are not storing anything in session state beforehand. [If you don't actually store something in Session State, you will get a new session on every request.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx).

> When using cookie-based session state, ASP.NET does not allocate storage for session data until the Session object is used. As a result, a new session ID is generated for each page request until the session object is accessed. If your application requires a static session ID for the entire session, you can either implement the Session_Start method in the application's Global.asax file and store data in the Session object to fix the session ID, or you can use code in another part of your application to explicitly store data in the Session object.

So to reiterate, to eliminate the call to `Session_Start`, you need to put something in session state before redirecting.

```
Session["TheKey"] = "TheValue";
return RedirectToAction("TheAction");
```

Comment: I have added code from which i am calling RedirectToAction method .as you can see i am filling Session variables just before RedirectToAction method but when RedirectToaction is called it calls Session_Start and all session values set previously are cleared.